# Maven + .NET + Sonar v4.5.1 + Analysis Bootstrapper for Visual Studio Projects

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, maven, sonarqube

I am trying to run a sonar(v 4.5.1) build for .NET C# project using Maven 3.2.3. I face the following error and struck here with this and not able to proceed further.

Error Log:

```
[INFO] [13:06:21.552] The import of some StyleCop issues were skipped. See DEBUG logs for details.
[INFO] [13:06:21.553] Sensor org.sonar.plugins.stylecop.StyleCopSensor@19bcfc1 done: 11995 ms
[INFO] [13:06:21.555] Sensor JMeterSensor...
[INFO] [13:06:21.555] Sensor JMeterSensor done: 0 ms
[INFO] [13:06:21.555] Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.squid.CSharpSquidSensor@58aa13...
[INFO] [13:06:21.607] 53 source files to be analyzed
[INFO] [13:06:22.291] 53/53 source files analyzed
[INFO] [13:06:22.352] Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.squid.CSharpSquidSensor@58aa13 done: 797 ms
[INFO] [13:06:22.352] Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.core.CSharpFxCopProvider$CSharpFxCopSensor@1060218...
[DEBUG] [13:06:22.354] Release semaphore on project : org.sonar.api.resources.Project@1c60683[id=10140,key=OrgName:ProjectName,qualifier=TRK], with key batch-OrgName:ProjectName
[ERROR] The property "sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly" must be set and the project must have been built to execute FxCop rules. This property can be automatically set by the Analysis Bootstrapper for Visual Studio Projects plugin, see: http://docs.codehaus.org/x/TAA1Dg.If you wish to skip the analysis of not built projects, set the property "sonar.visualstudio.skipIfNotBuilt".
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 02:16 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-12-23T13:06:22-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/130M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin:4.5.1:sonar (default-cli) on project OrgName:ProjectName: The property "sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly" must be set and the project must have been built to execute FxCop rules. This property can be automatically set by the Analysis Bootstrapper for Visual Studio Projects plugin, see: http://docs.codehaus.org/x/TAA1Dg.If you wish to skip the analysis of not built projects, set the property "sonar.visualstudio.skipIfNotBuilt". -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin:4.5.1:sonar (default-cli) on project OrgName-ProjectName: The property "sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly" must be set and the project must have been built to execute FxCop rules. This property can be automatically set by the Analysis Bootstrapper for Visual Studio Projects plugin, see: http://docs.codehaus.org/x/TAA1Dg.If you wish to skip the analysis of not built projects, set the property "sonar.visualstudio.skipIfNotBuilt".
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: The property "sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly" must be set and the project must have been built to execute FxCop rules. This property can be automatically set by the Analysis Bootstrapper for Visual Studio Projects plugin, see: http://docs.codehaus.org/x/TAA1Dg. If you wish to skip the analysis of not built projects, set the property "sonar.visualstudio.skipIfNotBuilt".
        at org.sonar.maven.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:37)
        at org.sonar.maven.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:175)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The property "sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly" must be set and the project must have been built to execute FxCop rules. This property can be automatically set by the Analysis Bootstrapper for Visual Studio Projects plugin, see: http://docs.codehaus.org/x/TAA1Dg. If you wish to skip the analysis of not built projects, set the property "sonar.visualstudio.skipIfNotBuilt".
        at org.sonar.plugins.fxcop.FxCopConfiguration.checkMandatoryProperties(FxCopConfiguration.java:94)
        at org.sonar.plugins.fxcop.FxCopConfiguration.checkProperties(FxCopConfiguration.java:86)
        at org.sonar.plugins.fxcop.FxCopSensor.analyse(FxCopSensor.java:91)
        at org.sonar.plugins.fxcop.FxCopSensor.analyse(FxCopSensor.java:86)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:79)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:70)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:119)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:194)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:233)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:228)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:226)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:221)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:64)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:51)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:125)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:173)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
        at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
        at org.sonar.maven.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:173)
        ... 21 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

When i set the property to

```
sonar.visualstudio.skipIfNotBuilt=true
```

I get the error like this.

```
[ERROR] No Visual Studio projects were found.
```

My pom.xml configurations are,

```
    <sonar.visualstudio.enable>true</sonar.visualstudio.enable>
    <sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.solution.file>projetName.sln</sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.solution.file>
    <visual.test.project.pattern>*.Tests</visual.test.project.pattern>
    <dotnet.tool.version>4.5</dotnet.tool.version>
    <sonar.language>cs</sonar.language>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <sonar.cs.fxcop.fxCopCmdPath><program_files>/Fxcop/FxCopCmd.exe</sonar.cs.fxcop.fxCopCmdPath>
    <sonar.stylecop.msBuildPath>C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/MSBuild.exe</sonar.stylecop.msBuildPath>
    <sonar.stylecop.styleCopDllPath><program_files>/StyleCop 4.7/StyleCop.dll</sonar.stylecop.styleCopDllPath>
    <sonar.fxcop.installDirectory><program_files>/Fxcop</sonar.fxcop.installDirectory>
```

Please suggest me a solution for this.

Comment: Any one faced this issue already ?

Comment: Any answers for my question ?

Comment: Any one faced this issue ?? Kindly reply...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved having entry for fxcop assembly for all my sub modules.

```
sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly=subproject1/bin/Debug/subproject1.dll
sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly=subproject2/bin/Debug/subproject2.dll  
sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly=subproject3/bin/subproject3.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try setting one of the below properties.  I am not sure what type of application you are building, but i could not get my MVC project to pass this step without setting the fxcop directories property to be my lib folder or the bin output folder.

```
sonar.cs.fxcop.directories=
sonar.visualstudio.outputPaths=
```

and change your visual studio solution property to the following

```
sonar.visualstudio.solution=projetName.sln
```

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Bootstrapper+for+Visual+Studio+Projects+Plugin

Comment: I finally resolved having entry for fxcop assembly for all my sub modules.  <br/>

sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly=subproject1/bin/Debug/subproject1.dll  <br/>
sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly=subproject2/bin/Debug/subproject2.dll  <br/>
sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly=subproject3/bin/subproject3.dll